# pip and virtualenv: Remove non-requirements

Tags: virtualenv, pip

I've been using `pip` with `virtualenv`, and I'm really liking it. I keep all my requirements in a `requirements.txt` file obtained with this command:

```
`pip freeze > requirements.txt`
```

The only thing that I've really been trying to figure out is this:
**How can I remove packages that aren't in my requirements file?**

This would be really helpful for when I am moving between different branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to do the following:

```
virtualenv --clear PATH_TO_VENV
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However, it's a bit of a drastic solution...